# Socket.IO heartbeat not sent

Tags: android, socket.io, socket.io-java-client

I've been running a Socket.IO server (https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) , communicating with a client (https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java) that runs on an Android emulator. The emulator is hosted on the machine that runs the server. I was able to create the initial connection from the client to the server, and successfully send a message (client to server), but shortly after that the heartbeat failed and the connection was broken:

> DEBUG [07:17:45.470]   c.c.socketio.transport.NamespaceClient: Client
>   157e4f73-e26d-459c-ac1c-506628b66a09 for namespace  has been
>   disconnected  DEBUG [07:17:45.470] 
>   c.c.socketio.SocketIOChannelInitializer: Client with sessionId:
>   157e4f73-e26d-459c-ac1c-506628b66a09 disconnected  DEBUG
>   [07:17:45.470]   c.c.socketio.transport.NamespaceClient: Client
>   157e4f73-e26d-459c-ac1c-506628b66a09 for namespace /android/ has been
>   disconnected  DEBUG [07:17:45.471]
>   c.c.socketio.handler.ClientHead: 157e4f73-e26d-459c-ac1c-506628b66a09
>   removed due to ping timeout  DEBUG [07:17:46.119]
>   c.c.s.transport.WebSocketTransport: Client with was already
>   disconnected. Channel closed!

Server code:

```
Configuration serverConfig = new Configuration();
serverConfig.setHostname(MACHINE_IP);
serverConfig.setPort(8082);
serverConfig.setPingTimeout(20);
SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(serverConfig);
server.addNamespace("/android/")
server.start()
```

Client code:

```
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
options.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
options.reconnectionAttempts = 5;
options.reconnectionDelay = 10000;
Socket socket = IO.socket(MACHINE_IP + ":8082/android/", options)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve the problem myself (there may be other solutions as well).

What I did was:

1. Start the server on localhost - as it isn't necessary for it to be visible outside of the machine
2. Connect the client to [10.0.2.2](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) - which is the way for the emulator to access its host localhost